# textarea - get world before cursor & replace it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to translate the text in a `textarea`. when I press the `space` key, an ajax request is made with the text in that field & then replaced by the response text.

But It would be better if I could just make an ajax request with the single word just before that space & then replace only that word by the response word. This way I could translate word by word & that's exactly what I need.

Any ideas? Please share if you have any.

Comment: But It would be better if you post your code

Comment: I tried what I said in the first paragraph. Didn't yet tried the second paragraph. need ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function getLast returns the last word in the textarea

```
function getLast(o) {
    return ("" + o).replace(/[\s-]+$/, '').split(/[\s-]/).pop();
}
```

If the spacebar is pressed (keyCode 32), then call the getLast function on the value of the textarea. Then make an AJAX call passing the last word as a variable.

```
$('#textArea').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        var textArea = $('textArea');
        var word = getLast(textArea.val());
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.cfm?fuseaction=user.test2",
            data: {
                currentWord: word
            }
        }).done(function(translation) {
            var translatedWord = $.trim(translation);
            var string = textArea.val();
            string = string.replace(word, translatedWord);
            textArea.val(string);
        });
    }
});​
```

I feel like your best bet would be to translate the entire textarea word by word at the end, however.

Comment: +1, seems good! what about updating the word? what if I keep typing & don't wait for the response to be replaced?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you know how to retrieve the string in the text input.

To isolate the last word, you will have to look for non word characters surrounding word characters near the end of your string. I suggest using [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Remark: this is not an answer element, but I think word by word translation is a not a good idea and putting the translation output in the same area as input can be very painful to use. You should probably make a global translation and have your output somewhere else in the screen and have it updated when the input changes, like in google translate for example.

Comment: I understand that. But I think that wouldn't be that much bad, if user sees words getting translated after typing :)

Comment: @sha404 Yes, for the nominal case of "typing text" you are right. But there are a lot of minority cases. Usually when you type a text, there are thing like typing "backspace", editing something else that the last word, copy/pasting, etc... And all of this features would be broken with the interaction you are planning to implement.